# Can Xcode be used to create very simple games?

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode

I am brand new to Xcode, and I am also brand new Objective-C programmer.

I was wondering if it is possible to create simple Mac games with Xcode. If it's not possible, could you recommend me some good, cheap game engines?

Comment: Xcode is simply an IDE. It's probably better if you ask (or search yourself) for creating games using Objective-C, for example.

Comment: Could you guys tell me where I can find Objective-C, mac game creation tutorials?

Comment: [Cocos2D-iPhone](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) is a good choice! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xcode can indeed be used to create games. You can do anything a Mac/iOS device is capable of by programming in Xcode.

I think you should focus on what part of the project you want to focus on. As you state you are a brand new Objective-C programmer (welcome). In my opinion it would be quite a mouth full to try and just into Objective-C programming whilst taking on Xcode AND game development (starting with engine design continuing with game design).

If the purpose is to write great games - get a nice engine that fits your needs (3D/2D/??) - have a look at Unity if you like. If the focus is actually learning programming Objective-C and/or Xcode I'd recommend that you make some small utility programs before jumping on to game development. If the point is to simply do game programming consider the alternatives to Objective-C and Xcode - pure C/C++ or even Java.

All that said - I wish you the best of luck in your adventure!

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like to learn Objective-C, I suggest you have a look at [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/). It's an open-source 2d engine (written in Objective-C) that allows you to write games for iOS or Mac OS using XCode.

It's not as easy to create games with as with a package like Unity, but there are lots of tutorials (and even books) for cocos2d to be found. A good place to start with lots of tutorials is [Ray Wenderlichs site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials).

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely! XCode is the standard programming IDE for the Mac and iOS. So if your goal is making a game for iOS, you will probably be using XCode along with a few other helping technologies of your choice (e.g. OpenGL ES 2.0).

But since you mentioned game engines I'd also recommend you to use one, since they'll save you a lot of time and effort:

- If you are planning to make a 2D game take a look at Cocos2D
  ( http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/ ). It's quite popular.
- And if you're planning to make a 3D game, maybe Unity ( http://unity3d.com/unity/ )  would be a good bet for you. It's not Objective-C but it can publish for iOS too, if that's your goal.

Comment: I used unity once, but it turned out to be very complicated :( Thanks for the tips :D

Comment: @CocoaCoder Quite honestly: If you think Unity is very complicated, then coding objective-c from scratch is going to be complicated as well.

Comment: @bummzack I will do my best to try out unity :D