# How can I create a simple, sprite-based Mac game in Xcode?

Tags: game-design, sprites

I am using Xcode and I am new to Objective-C and Cocoa programming. I want to create a very simple sprite game in Xcode, but I do not know what code I should type or where/how to get started.

It's a simple game where you play as a ball (I was thinking of using an `NSButton` with a picture) and you jump around until you touch a flag to complete the level. I also want to add a system of sprite detection so that you can kill enemies if you jump on their heads.

Comment: Questions about "How to make an entire Game" are considered off-topic here. Either look for resources/tutorials on the web or get a book about game programming in Objective-C. Feel free to ask more specific questions once you got the basics covered.

Comment: I cannot find any good books and I couldn't find any useful information online... Thanks anyways :D

Comment: That's probably because most games written for the mac would use OpenGL, not Cocoa.

Comment: In your [other question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20715/can-xcode-be-used-to-create-very-simple-games), several people pointed out cocos2d which can be used to create games for Mac OS X. There are tons of tutorials/resources for cocos2d and while most of them are about iOS, there are also some for Mac OS to be found (basics are the same for both platforms anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a game engine called Cocos2d.  Check that out.  It's pretty easy to use.